# Faced SyntaxError: Identifier expected in React

Tags: reactjs

I was working in React and I have the following component:

```
 <DatePicker
                label="With dateFormat YYYY-MM-DD"
                onChange={action('onChange')}
                dateFormat='YYYY-MM-DD' | 'YYYY-DD-MM' | 'YYYY-M-D'
            />
```

But is it correct to define props like this dateFormat='YYYY-MM-DD' | 'YYYY-DD-MM' | 'YYYY-M-D'

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? In any case, why would you do a bitwise or on a string?

Comment: @DennisVash, string shows error of SyntaxError: Identifier expected. How is it possible to fix it. I want to achieve OR

Comment: what do you mean "I want to achieve OR", or operator is `||` , bitwise or is `|`

Answer (score 0):

You're doing wrong, Please have a look as below:

```js
<DatePicker
  label="With dateFormat YYYY-MM-DD"
  onChange={action('onChange')}
  dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
/>
```

Please remove the '|' from the dateFormat props, you can not add multiple formats at the same time. Have a look below example:

```js
<DatePicker
  selected={startDate}
  onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
  showTimeSelect
  timeFormat="HH:mm"
  timeIntervals={15}
  timeCaption="time"
  dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
/>
```

I hope it would help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you trying to say: "format the label with one of the given `dateFormat`s":

```
<DatePicker
  label="With dateFormat YYYY-MM-DD"
  onChange={action('onChange')}
  dateFormat={['YYYY-MM-DD', 'YYYY-DD-MM', 'YYYY-M-D']}
/>
```